# Consuming web service from Adobe FLEX

Tags: wcf, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I am new to FLEX and I want to invoke a service that returns a string object:

```
    <mx:WebService id = "myService" wsdl = "http://myhost.com/Service1.svc?wsdl">
        <mx:operation name = "opName" resultFormat = "object" />
    </mx:WebService>
```

What is the syntax to store the string returned by the service in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, use the `result` handler:

```
<mx:WebService ... result="myResultHandler(event)">

public function myResultHandler(e:ResultEvent):void {
    myVar = e.result;
}
```

See also see: [reference1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html) and [reference2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractService.html#event:result)